# How to let user modifying content of pages with rails ? Query for text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm developing a website with Ruby on Rails.

I want to find the better way to let users (not developers) to edit text on some pages (like the index...). (like a CMS ?)

Actually they had to get the page through FTP, to edit the text and to put the new file on the server (through FTP).

It's a very very bad practice and I wanted to know if someone has an idea to solve this problem ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would be the same as the basic Rails CRUD operations. Just make a model/controller representing page content, and an edit view for the controller. Then on the pages you want text to be editable, instead of having the content directly on the page just use a view partial.

Of course, you would probably also want to implement some type of authentication to make sure not just everyone can edit pages.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one thing you could do is add a model to your database called "Content" or "Copy" which represents some text on a page. Then you could use polymorphic association to link the content/copy to your actual model. For instance, if you had a page with a list of products on it, you'd likely have a Product model in your database. You could do something like this:

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contentable, :polymorphic => true # excuse my lame naming here
  # this model would need two fields to make it polymorphic:
  # contentable_id <-- Integer representing the record that owns it
  # contentable_type <-- String representing the kind of model (Class) that owns it
  # An example would look like:
  # contentable_id: 4 <--- Product ID 4 in your products table
  # contentable_type: Product <--- Tells the rails app which model owns this record

  # You'd also want a text field in this model where you store the page text that your
  # users enter.
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contents, :as => :contentable # again forgive my naming
end
```

In this scenario, when the product page renders, you could call @product.contents to retrieve all the text users have entered for this product. If you don't want to use two separate models like this, you could put a text field directly on the Product model itself and have users enter text there.